# Android how to resize (scale) an xml vector icon programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

This is driving me crazy. I would like to be able to resize an xml vector drawable icon programmatically in order to use it in an ImageView.

This is what I've done so far which is not working

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_marker,null);
drawable.setBounds(0,0,512,512);
imageVenue.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

The vector icon `ic_marker` is not resized. It just keeps the hardcoded width and height values every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the width and height of your imageview programmatically. Since vector drawables will preserve the original quality of the image, this will make the desired output happen.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
int width = 60;
int height = 60;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
iv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thank you. While this solution works great I was hoping for an alternative where I scale my drawable directly and then place it in imageview without messing with imageview params itself. I'm gonna do a reseach on it and if this is impossible to achive the way I want, I will accept your answer

Comment: I would recommend to use different png files as typical drawables, with different sizes for different devices. Way to go :)

Comment: yeap I know, but my whole point here is to use vector drawables so that I don't need to have png files with different sizes

Comment: This does not work if the drawable is part of a TextView using `app:drawableEndCompat`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently facing the same problem.

I'm trying something like this, cause ViewParent has actually height set explicitly, so I use match_parent and set margins. It doesn't work all the time though, cause I simply use this view in a viewholder for RecyclerView... Also I've noticed that sometimes I see scaled up version with artifacts, sometimes full size, sometimes there are margins, and bigger margins... But it still might work for you, if you use it in a simpler scenario.

```
mImageViewFront.setImageDrawable(vectorDrawable);
final int paddingLR = mImageViewFront.getWidth() / 4;
final int paddingTB = mImageViewFront.getHeight() / 4;
LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.setMargins(paddingLR, paddingTB, paddingLR, paddingTB);
mImageViewFront.setLayoutParams(params);
```