# resize vectordrawable icon programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-vectordrawable

I am showing some VectorDrawable icon dynamically in my android project. 
However, I couldn't scale the icons in java layer using the below code:

```
VectorDrawable jDrawable = (VectorDrawable) getContext().getDrawable(nResourceID);

// resize the icon
jDrawable.setBounds(30, 30, 30, 30);

// set the icon in the button view
button.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(jDrawable, null, null, null);
```

**Note**: [Android how to resize (scale) an xml vector icon programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066207/android-how-to-resize-scale-an-xml-vector-icon-programmatically) the answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: You got me wrong! Sorry for being incomplete.

Answer (score 7):

`jDrawable.setBounds` doesn't work because of a bug in android.

One way to overcome the bug is to convert `VectorDrawable` to `Bitmap` and display it.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(jDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), jDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
jDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
jDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

Then use this `bitmap` to display something like below. First convert it to `BitmapDrawable`

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
buttonsetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(bd, null, null, null);
```

Also in your helper function you can return `bd`.

To use it on pre-23 API put this in `build.gradle`

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: Always getting the expected result!

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier for at least API > 21.
Assume that we have VectorDrawable from resources (example code to retrieve it):

```
val iconResource = context.resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.packageName)
val drawable = context.resources.getDrawable(iconResource, null)
```

For that VectorDrawable just set desired size:

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size)
```

And show drawable in button:

```
button.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawable, null, null)
```

That's it. But note to use setCompoundDrawables (not Intrinsic version)!