# VectorDrawable: How to resize the vectordrawable dynamically

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am using a custom view in which I have a rectangle and need to draw a VectorDrawable between the bounds.
I need to resize the size of the vectorDrawable on the go.
I am already using canvas to set the outer rectangle, so I cannot create another canvas using a bitmap.
This is what I am doing inside onDraw():

```
canvas!!.drawRect(mRect, mRadius!!,mRadius!!, mPaint)
vectorDrawable.mutate()
vectorDrawable.setBounds(mRect)
vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
```

If I try to create a bitmap and create a new canvas object:

```
var bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
var can : Canvas = Canvas(bmp)
```

Then my vectorDrawable is not seen.

Please let me know the best way to resize the vectorDrawable.

Comment: whats the size of that `Bitmap`? what is `getIntrinsicWidth` and `getIntrinsicHeight`?

Comment: Bitmap width is 126 and height is 90 , getIntrinsicWidth and height is 126

Comment: ok and what do you want that extra `Bitmap` for? why cannot you use `Drawable#draw` method?

Comment: I was referring to this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405761/9844419

Comment: `Drawable#setBounds` works just fine - you dont have any additional `Bitmap`

Comment: @pskink, The real problem is resizing the vectorDrawable.

Comment: ok so what problems do you have with `vectorDrawable.setBounds(mRect)`?

Comment: If you see this:
canvas!!.drawRect(mRect, mRadius!!,mRadius!!, mPaint)
vectorDrawable.mutate()
vectorDrawable.setBounds(mRect)
vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
My current vector drawable is getting the exact size as the bounds, however I need to resize/scale the vectorDrawable

Comment: i dont get you: you resize/scale the vectorDrawable by calling `setBounds` on it

Comment: @pskink, sorry if I misunderstood here, but are you suggesting to use setBounds to resize or scale?

Comment: yes, this is what `setBounds` is for

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will update you on this.